# Mapbox GL JS: build match expression based on multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have the following array:

```
var SplitUpLevels = [
 [ zoomLevel: 6, locationIDs: [1, 2, 3]],
 [ zoomLevel: 10, locationIDs: [4, 5, 6]],
];
```

I want to hide some icons on the map, based on an individual zoomlevel and only if the location ID is in the array. I get the values dynamically from a JSON source.

I already tried a simple forEach loop without any success:

```
"icon-opacity" : [
   "interpolate",
   ["linear"],
   ["zoom"],
   0,
   1,

   SplitUpLevels.forEach(function(SplitUpLevel) {

     SplitUpLevel.zoomlevel,
     [ "match", ["get", "Id"], SplitUpLevel.locationIDs, 0, 0 ] 

   }),

 … ]
```

I either get the response

> "icon-opacity: Expected an even number of arguments."

or

> "icon-opacity[5]: Input/output pairs for "interpolate" expressions
>   must be defined using literal numeric values (not computed
>   expressions) for the input values."

What's the best way to build such an expression, based on a dynamic source.

Comment: It's not really possible to evaluate a function within the style-spec you're passing to your layer (which it looks like you're trying to do). But you should be able to do your dynamic styling through some combination of zoom-based styling (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/change-building-color-based-on-zoom-level/) and data-driven properties (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is searching for a solution: create an expression array and use it to add the layer:

```
var iconopacity = ["interpolate",
                   "linear",
                   "zoom"]
```

Then push the expression for each array in the json file

```
SplitUpLevels.forEach(function(SplitUpLevel) {
  iconopacity.push(SplitUpLevel.zoomlevel, [ "match", ["get", "Id"], SplitUpLevel.locationIDs, 0, 0 ]);
}
```

Then add the new layer

```
  map.addLayer({
   […]
   "paint" : {
    "icon-opacity" : iconopacity
   }
  });
```

After a long search I still decided to adapt the data in advance using a PHP script instead of creating complicated filter rules.